# shouldComponentUpdate won't be called

Tags: reactjs

I want my `Video` component not to rerender by returning false in `shouldComponentUpdate`. However `shouldComponentUpdate` is not being called.

Expected behaviour: when clicking on the video (clickHandler), `shouldComponentUpdate` will be called and returns false.

Actual behaviour: when clicking on the video (clickHandler), the component rerenders and logs 'render component'.

Below you can find my code:

Video.js

```
class Video extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log('shouldupdate video');

    return false;
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    if (this.props.controls) {
      this.props.toggleVideoPlayer();
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render component');

    return (
      <div className={s.container} onClick={this.clickHandler}>
        <video className={s.video} ref={this.video} autoPlay loop>
          <track kind="captions" />
          <source src={this.props.mp4} type="video/mp4" />
          {this.props.ogv && <source src={this.props.ogv} type="video/ogg" />}
        </video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('home: component did mount');
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log('home: should component update.');

    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          image={hero}
          title="Home page"
        />

        <Video mp4="http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc.mp4" {...this.props} controls />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPages(api.API_PAGES);
    this.props.fetchPosts(api.API_POSTS);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.props.pages.isFetching && this.props.pages.data &&
          <div>
            <Navbar {...this.props} />

            <Layout {...this.props}>
              <Switch location={this.props.location}>
                <Route
                  path={routes.HOME}
                  exact
                  component={() => (
                    <Home
                      {...this.props}
                      page={findPage(this.props.pages, 'home')}
                    />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  path={routes.ABOUT}
                  component={() => (
                    <About
                      {...this.props}
                      page={findPage(this.props.pages, 'informatie')}
                    />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  path={routes.NEWS}
                  exact
                  component={() => (
                    <News
                      {...this.props}
                      posts={this.props.posts}
                      page={findPage(this.props.pages, 'nieuws')}
                    />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  component={NotFound}
                />
              </Switch>
            </Layout>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `toggleVideoPlayer` do? It might be that your component is thrown away entirely, and a new one is created. Try to log in the `componentDidMount` hook and see if a new component is created.

Comment: That's because the component is rendered by the parent component. I suppose you change the state in the parent when calling toggleVideoPlayer which actually re-renders your video component

Comment: Probably it would be better to include the video player inside this component

Comment: @Tholle `toggleVideoPlayer` updates a state in redux

Comment: @MateiMihai So what I should do is put my `shouldComponentUpdate` function in my parent component and check if the state has changed. If so `return false`?

Comment: If you do that the video player will not be rendered anymore. The only solution I can see would be to render the video player inside the video component

Comment: So far I don't have a videoPlayer component yet. I only change a state in redux by calling `toggleVideoPlayer` which changes the state of `videoIsPlaying` to true or false. I'm calling my `Video` component in my `Home` component which looks like this (see above: UPDATE).

Comment: @MateiMihai when I click on the `Video` component my `Home` component will be rerendered. `componentDidMount` logs 'home did mount'.

Comment: Then yes, just try to return  false on the Home's component shouldComponentUpdate method. But be careful about it. I would add a flag to skip it only when you are toggling the video play.

Comment: @MateiMihai Also `shouldComponentUpdate` is not being called in my `Home` component. Why is that?. My `Home` component is called in `App` (see above: UPDATE).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173880/discussion-between-ruud-luijten-and-matei-mihai).